# jQuery Accordion Menu at the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have been researching for a good while on this one but have not found a good answer for my problem.

So, I have created a **jQuery accordion** menu that sticks at the bottom of an unscrollable page, which means I want *the children of each submenu element to slide vertically from bottom to top*, and not the other way around. This means the parent element (aka. the title of the section of the menu) should still be on top, displaying the other elements below itself.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDRY7/3/) with the current state of my menu, but this is how my jQuery code looks like by now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Navmenu h3").click(function(){
$(“#Navmenu ul ul”).slideUp();
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
    {
    $(this).next().slideDown();
    } else { $(this).next().slideUp(); }
    })
})
```

Could someone give me a hint/solution to get this right?
I am new to this but really tried to find a solution. Maybe I just used the wrong tagwords on my search...

Any help would be really appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Set the position of the Navmenu to be relative to the bottom, not the top.

```
#Navmenu {
    bottom: 1%; /* NOT top: 85%; */
}
```

Comment: Easy at it sounds, this was my main mistake.
For a reason I could not use 'bottom' value before and so I used the 'top' value. Now it's all good. Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Code seems overly complicated.  I would use jQuery.toggle instead.

Example:

You have two UL (each containing its subset of links)

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UkVCj/3/

JS:

```
$("#MenuToggle1").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();     
    $('#myMenu ul#first').toggle('slow');
});
```

CSS:

```
$("#MenuToggle2").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();     
    $('#myMenu ul#second').toggle('slow');
});

#myMenu ul#first, #myMenu ul#second{
    display: none;
}

#myMenu ul#second{
    background-color: rgb(180,180,180);
}

#myMenu ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
}
#myMenu{
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
        background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
}
```

** Please optimize this code before use, just wanted to show you the general concept.

Comment: The solution was actually more simple than I thought it'd be but yeah, my code seemed overly complicated. I've taken note for future reference. ;) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is the part of CSS. Update the below id in CSS

```
#Navmenu {
    top: 85%;    //remove this line
    bottom: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, here is a simplified version of the script you need:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Navmenu h3").click(function () {
                $(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle();
            });
        });
```

Then, what you really need is to make the CSS on the ul ul selector, position:absolute:

```
 #Navmenu ul ul {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:75px;
}
```

Then position them directly from the bottom as I have above, or similar: http://jsfiddle.net/t4KjC/2/

I hope this helps and good luck with your menu!